# Stackdriver Job Monitoring -Big query or Dataflow

Tags: dataflow, stackdriver

How we can check Slow job performance and Job recovery through Stackdriver , am looking for Dataflow or Big query jobs .

Answer (score 0):

In regards to this inquiry, you can always go to the public documentation page for GCP [here](https://cloud.google.com/) to ask general questions in regards to GCP.

In regards to your inquiry, I have attached an article on how you can monitor your Dataflow pipelines using Stackdriver Monitoring [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stackdriver-monitoring).

YOu can also follow this [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#metrics) on how you can use Stackdriver Monitoring to monitor your jobs within BigQuery.

Comment: Am looking mainly for Job recovery mechanism through stackdriver , is it possible or not ? And also if any of the Dataflow job stage fails how to restart the pipeline from the same step .

Comment: What do you mean by "Job recovery"? Stackdriver Monitoring will monitor your resources using the metrics you choose.  It will also alert you if you created an Alert Policy using the metrics you choose as well; however, there is no metric within Stackdriver that will automatically restart the Dataflow Job.